# Built in operator class timestamptz_minmax_ops not supproted for creating index in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

It seems like built in operator class for postgres listed in the offical [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/brin-builtin-opclasses.html) is not supported when creating indexes.

For example the following run into error

```
CREATE INDEX my_index_name
    ON public.my_table USING btree
    (my_column timestamptz_minmax_ops)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

while this is ok

```
CREATE INDEX my_index_name
    ON public.my_table USING btree
    (my_column timestamptz_ops)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Even though `timestamptz_minmax_ops` is listed as the name of the operator class in the doc.

Am I missing something?

Comment: From your link: "*Built-in **BRIN** Operator Classes*"

Answer (score 2):

The operator class `timestamptz_minmax_ops` is for the `brin` access method and not for `btree`, hence the error.

You can use this operator class only if the index is created `USING brin`, while your index, lacking a `USING` clause, uses the default access method `btree`.

To help you on with your goal: Why do you want `timestamptz_minmax_ops`? What query should the index speed up?

Comment: `Collation` was a typo, thanks for pointing that out, but what is the difference between `brin` vs `btree`?

Comment: @Jal "Built-in BRIN Operator Classes" is *bold* in your referenced docs. And you can find info on BRIN here: https://www.google.ie/search?q=btree+brin&oq=btree+brin

Comment: I have changed the answer, hopefully it is more helpful now.

Comment: @Jal: [Index types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-types.html) in the manual